# Plugins installation failed because "network access is disabled"

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-3

Any idea how to solve the problem with the plugin installation failed in qgis 3.0? I cannot run the installation for some plugins and it is because "network access is disabled".

Comment: just faced the problem in an old 3.0.0 version on win... seems related with a qt bug in a specific build and running env
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-55180
Nor updating to 3.0.2 solve the problem.